# 2 vowels in a word using regex

Tags: php, html

I am given a sentence and I have to find out the words containing at least 2 vowels and print the same.
Can someone tell me if what I did was right or wrong?
preg_match('/[aeiou].*[aeiou]/')
Will this work for all words?

```
<?php
$line = $_POST["input"];
$array = preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
//our line has been separated into Strings
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++)
{
    if(preg_match('/[aeiou].*[aeiou]/', $array[$i], $matches))
    {
        print($array[$i]." ");
    }
} 
?>
```

The html file where I take the input is:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My web page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        Enter the sentence <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="input" ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not how you ask a question here on SO. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a closer look to your regexp:

- `[aeiou]` selects a lower case a,e,i,o or u
- `.*` selects any character (this is as far as I know the most greedy thing you can do at a regexp). This will match any input
- `[aeiou]` again selects the lower case vowels

The `.*` in between is the reason why you always select any word.

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve. If it is selecting a word with 2 vowels than your regex might be something like this one `[aeiou][^ ]*[aeiou]`. This selects a vowel everything which is not a whitespace (maybe you not a better separator of words e.g tabs, commas brackets etc. this again depends on your use case) and the next vowel.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is working. Though why  '/[aeiou]{2}/' won't work?

Comment: Because that would select two consecutive vowels. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```
$line = $_POST["string"];
        $array = preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
        //our line has been separated into Strings
        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++)
        {
            $num = preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i', $array[$i], $matches);
            if($num >= 2)
            {
                print($array[$i]." ");
            }
        }
```

Try this.